# SSMS is crashing and SSMS Toolbar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I'm new in SQL Server and i have installed SQL Server on my system for testing purpose. 
Issue 1: I want to convert the name of all the toolbar in menu tab to icon. I have no clue from where does it got changed and i need to change to icon option. I have option to add and/or remove buttons but it doesn't have any icon in it. So, it's confusing without the icon to change it.

Attached are the image 1 and 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Vsn.png)

[image]

Issue 2: SSMS keep on crashing. If i open any new table and select top 100 rows, it gives me result correct but when i select any row values and copy any values from the table, it crashes and automatically restart.

For second problem, i have followed few links to solve it, but after running the query, if i copy a value from the result grid, it crashes there.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/baaace41-1286-4303-b31f-0ac935452e95/why-is-ssms-1791-crashing?forum=sqltools

If anyone have any suggestion, it will be very useful for me.

Comment: Please specify the version of SSMS. You can download latest SSMS from --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#ssms-180-preview-7

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your instance of Management Studio is either corrupt or is in need of repair.

This could be for many reasons, including installing it on an unsupported version of Windows, or an unsupported version of .NET. I have previously seen problems like this when someone has installed Sql Server 2012 on Windows Server 2016 without enabling .NET 3.5 Runtime.

What I recommend you do, is to remove the version of SSMS that comes pre-packed with Sql Server 2012 and install the standalone version instead.

To uninstall your existing version of SSMS, follow the steps below:

1. Open Programs and Features (type appwiz.cpl in Run/CMD)
2. Locate Sql Server 2012 and select Uninstall/Change.
3. Go through the wizard, choosing the Sql Server instance you want to modify.
4. Untick Management Tools - Basic and Management Tools - Complete.
5. Click next to skip through all of the remaining steps.
6. Click finish to uninstall SSMS.

Once you have completely unsintalled the existing version of SSMS, go to [Download Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017), then download and install the latest version.

As always, check that your system meets the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#minimize-installation-reboots) for SSMS before attempting the install.